# Formatting issue in ActiveAdmin dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm having an issue pulling the correct information into a dashboard column using ActiveAdmin. If anyone could help me wrap my head around this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

The issue I'm having is retaining the data from an associated class with the current record I'm displaying (line 6 below).

Here is the column I've created:

```
  column do
    panel "Recent Beacons" do
      table_for Beacon.limit(20) do
        column("Mac address") { |b| link_to b.mac_address, admin_beacon_path(b) }
        column "Last seen", :updated_at
        column("House") { |b| link_to b.root_house, admin_house_path(b.root_house.id) }
        column("Status") { |b| b.online? ? status_tag('Online', :green) : status_tag('Offline', :red) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Using binding.pry I'm able to perform a `b.meters.pop.circuit.root` and return the correct value I'm looking for. However it ActiveAdmin doesn't like this and the page errors with the following `undefined method circuit for nil:NilClass`.  Trying to clean up the code a bit I wrote a `root_house` method.

```
  def root_house
    meters.pop.circuit.root
  end
```

ActiveAdmin has left me a bit confused and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what is `meters` in your root_house method?  The error "undefined method circuit for nil:NilClass` suggests that whatever `meters` is is nil.

Comment: That is helpful.. Thanks. My train of thought was that circuits was returning nil.

Meters is another model that beacons point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dirty fix for this, refactor as you wish:

```
  def root_house
    if meters && meters.pop && meters.pop.circuit
      meters.pop.circuit.root
    else
    'object is not present'
    end
  end
```

So I'm only going to call `meters.pop.circuit.root` if `meters` and `meters.pop` and `meters.pop.ciruit` is not nil.

Google null object pattern and law of Demeter ruby for a cleaner solution, also you can use `delegate` method, [this](https://github.com/anonyo/rails_anti_patterns/blob/master/law_of_demeter.rb) might be helpful.

Comment: That worked like a champ! I wish I have more than one upvote to give!

Really appreciate you pointing me in the 'delegate' direction.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!